# How to add an empty row after a definite row in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, concatenation

I'm working with a huge dataframe in python and sometimes I need to add an empty row or several rows in a definite position to dataframe. For this question I create a small dataframe df in order to show, what I want to achieve.

```
>  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size = (3,3)), columns =
> ['A','B','C'])
>        A  B  C
>     0  4  5  2
>     1  6  7  0
>     2  8  1  9
```

Let's say I need to add an empty row, if I have a zero-value in the column 'C'. Here the empty row should be added after the second row. So at the end I want to have a new dataframe like:

```
>new_df
>        A    B    C
>     0  4    5    2
>     1  6    7    0
>     2  nan  nan  nan
>     3  8    1    9
```

I tried with concat and append, but I didn't get what I want to. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
l = df[df['C']==0].index.tolist()
for c, i in enumerate(l):
    dfs = np.split(df, [i+1+c])
    df = pd.concat([dfs[0], pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]], columns=df.columns), dfs[1]], ignore_index=True)
print df
```

Input:

```
   A  B  C
0  4  3  0
1  4  0  4
2  4  4  2
3  3  2  1
4  3  1  2
5  4  1  4
6  1  0  4
7  0  2  0
8  2  0  3
9  4  1  3
```

Output:

```
    A    B    C
0   4.0  3.0  0.0
1   NaN  NaN  NaN
2   4.0  0.0  4.0
3   4.0  4.0  2.0
4   3.0  2.0  1.0
5   3.0  1.0  2.0
6   4.0  1.0  4.0
7   1.0  0.0  4.0
8   0.0  2.0  0.0
9   NaN  NaN  NaN
10  2.0  0.0  3.0
11  4.0  1.0  3.0
```

Last thing: it can happen that the last row has 0 in 'C', so you can add:

```
if df["C"].iloc[-1] == 0 :
    df.loc[len(df)] = [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works also with my real dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Try using slice.

First, you need to find the rows where C == 0. So let's create a bool df for this. I'll just name it 'a':

```
a = (df['C'] == 0)
```

So, whenever C == 0, a == True.

Now we need to find the index of each row where C == 0, create an empty row and add it to the df:

```
df2 = df.copy() #make a copy because we want to be safe here
for i in df.loc[a].index:
    empty_row = pd.DataFrame([], index=[i]) #creating the empty data
    j = i + 1 #just to get things easier to read
    df2 = pd.concat([df2.ix[:i], empty_row, df2.ix[j:]]) #slicing the df

df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True) #reset the index
```

I must say... I don't know the size of your df and if this is fast enough, but give it a  try

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and for your detailed explanation. It works!

Answer (score 1):

In case you know the index where you want to insert a new row, `concat` can be a solution.

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  4  7
# 1  2  5  8
# 2  3  6  9
```

Your new row as a dataframe with index 1:

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.nan, 'B': np.nan,'C': np.nan}, index=[1])
```

Inserting your new row after the second row:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.loc[:1], new_row, df.loc[2:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
#      A    B    C
# 0  1.0  4.0  7.0
# 1  2.0  5.0  8.0
# 2  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 3  3.0  6.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work for you:

```
for key, row in df.iterrows():
    if  row['C'] == 0:
        df.loc[key+1] = pd.Series([np.nan])
```

Comment: using for loop may not be a good choice as it was mentioned that data is huge.